# Métodos diferentes chamam um método de validação, quero saber qual o método que chamou a validação

Tags: php

Tenho dois métodos que chamam um mesmo método. Nesse método que foi chamado (no caso, o validate()), quero saber qual foi o método que o chamou.

```
    public function increase()
    {
        $this->validate();
    }

    public function decrease()
    {
        $this->validate();
    }

    private function validate()
    {
        echo 'Quem me chamou? increase() ou decrease()?';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No php tem a função [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) que 'gera um backtrace', mas gera no método atual

```
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
```

Mas podemos voltar o backtrace em um nivel para ver de onde veio a chamada desse método

```
    array_shift($backtrace); 
    var_dump($backtrace);
```

Comment: Certíssimo! Era exatamente isso que precisava, obrigado!